# Find string from a list and see if partially in an another list

Tags: java, groovy

So im trying to loop in the list A to find the elements from the list D and get something like this in the result:

```
Result="F10,12 ;FR300,157-159; FR300,161-162; FR300,183-184; FR300,185-186; FR300,187-188; FR300,191-192"



List<String> D= ("D","F10","FR300","FR300" )
List<String> A=("F10,12  | FR600,191-192 | FR400,191-192  | FR300,191-192  | FR300,187-188  | FR300,185-186  | FR300,183-184  | 3D  | FR300,157-159  | 1D  | FR300,161-162  | 300D")

String[] split_A = A.split("[|]")
String[] split_D = D.split("[,]")
for (s in split_A){
    for (item in split_D){
       if (item in s){
          println "Result"+ s
       }
    }
}
```

So my question is how to find the matches and be able to get somthing like the Result i have tried to use contains() but it didnt work correcly and i can't really add a variable with the specefic value like var=FR300,F10 cause i need to find somthening that will work if i run the script on a table that contain more than 400 records and the value from the column D can change ...
Thank you for your tips !

Comment: Why D is a list when it's just a string? The if should look like this `if( s.contains( item ) )`

Comment: It is a list but only in the example I put it like this just to show what’s inside my list but your are right I will edit it so people will not be confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay Finaly i did it like this .. i know it's not the best way

```
String[] split_A = A.split("[|]")
Set<String> myset = new HashSet<>();
String [] split_D = D.split("[,]");
for(int i=0;i<split_D.length;i++){
        myset.add(split_D[i]);  
}
for (String elem1: myset){
    for (elem2 in split_A){
        if( elem2.contains(elem1)){
            if (elem1!="D"){
                println elem2+"Found match"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative will be as follow :

```
for (String elem1: myset){
    for (elem2 in split_A){
        if( elem2.contains(elem1)){
            if (elem1!="D"){
//              println elem2+"Found match"
                Result.add([elem2])
            }
        }
    }
}
println Result
```